# Best way to query whether a many to many relation exists through prisma on a findMany query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, many-to-many, prisma, prisma2

I am using prisma ORM to query posts. My Post model looks like this

```
model Post {
  id      String   @id @default(uuid())
  content String @db.VarChar(1000)
  created DateTime @default(now())
  cursorNo Int @default(autoincrement())

  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], name: "postuser")
  userId String

  likes User[] @relation(references: [id], name: "postlikes")
  
}
```

And my user model looks like this

```
    model User {
  id        String  @id @default(uuid())
  firstname String
  lastname  String?
  username  String  @unique
  email     String  @unique
  password  String

  isActive Boolean @default(false)

  posts Post[] @relation(name: "postuser")
  liked_posts Post[]  @relation(name: "postlikes")

}
```

I want to write a query that returns a true or false value based on whether the user querying has liked that post or not and I am using `findMany()` method for that. I want my final query results to look like

```
[
{
    id: 1,
    content: "This is content"
    isLiked: False
},
{
    id: 2,
    content: "This is content 2"
    isLiked: True
}
]
```

What would be the most optimized way to implement this using prisma ORM and postgres?

TIA

Comment: Could you clarify if you want to query for a _single post_ or more than one post? Your question says "liked that post" which implies single but your desired result is an array with multiple posts, so it's a bit unclear.

Comment: I want to query multiple posts at once. I have also added the example of the array above. Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by _multiple posts_? How do you intend to specify which posts you want to query (or do you want to query all of them)? Maybe an example code snippet of the query you have tried so far might help here.

Comment: My query looks like this. At this point i am querying all the posts through cursor pagination 

`posts = await prisma.post.findMany(
            {
                take: 5,
                cursor: {id:  cursor},
                orderBy: {cursorNo: 'desc'},
                include: {likes: {select: {id: true}}}}
        )`